# Cudamemcpy2d error

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpu, cuda-gdb

cudamemcpy2d is returning error  -- following is the code
in the code below i have mentioned the line where i am getting an error. please look through and help me.

```
main(){
    int nrow = 16,ncol = 41; 
// 
    double **x = new double*[nrow];
    double **y = new double*[nrow];

    for(int i=0; i<nrow; i++){
        x[i] = new double[ncol];
        y[i] = new double[ncol];
    }

 // both x and y are filled with some values and function is called;
    function(x,y, nrow, ncol);
}

void function(double **x, double **y, int nrow, ncol){
      double *dev_x, *dev_y;
      size_t pitch_x, pitch_y;

      cudaMallocPitch((void **) &dev_x, &pitch_x, (n_col*sizeof(double)), nrow);
      cudaMallocPitch((void **) &dev_y, &pitch_y, (n_col*sizeof(double)), nrow);

   // this below line is returning error invalid value

      cudaMemcpy2D((void *)dev_x, pitch_x, (void *) *x, sizeof(double)*ncol, sizeof(double)*ncol, nrow, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  //launch a kernel
  kernel<<< 1, 1>>>(dev_x, dev_y, nrow, ncol);

   //below also gives the same error..

      cudaMemcpy2D((void *) *x, sizeof(double)*ncol, dev_x, pitch_x, sizeof(double)*ncol, nrow, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

please help thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have your directions reversed.  The first `cudaMemcpy2D` operation is copying from the Host to the Device, and you should specify `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice`.

Likewise the second `cudaMemcpy2D` is going in the other direction (based on the order of pointers you are passing) and so should specify `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost`.

The first pointer you pass to `cudaMemcpy2D` is the destination pointer.

Your usage of `*d_IntPts_X` may be a problem as well.  Normally you should pass a single pointer (`*`) flattened 1D array to cudaMemcpy type operations.  But since you haven't shown the definition of that variable/pointer, I can't say for sure.

**EDIT:** 
Now that you've changed the parameters, you can't use your `x` array this way in cudaMemcpy2D.  Instead, flatten x into a one dimensional array, perhaps something like this:

```
double *flat_x = new double[nrow*ncol];
```

and use that instead in your `cudaMemcpy2D` calls.

Also, there are *plenty* of questions like this on the CUDA tag.  Please search and read some of those before asking "why?"  "Doesn't it handle 2D matrices?" "What if I really want to use a 2D matrix?" etc.

Comment: Thankyou Robert Crovella.. i have edited the question. i will the parameter host to device and viceversa..